# How do I transplant black currants?

Tags: transplanting, currant

What should I do when transplanting black currants?
How deep should I plant it?
Where should I plant it?

Comment: What does  your research suggest so far?

Comment: 2 inches below the dividing mark is all i found.

Comment: Perhaps you should add that information to your question to show that you've done independent research which has failed to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

This is what we do and it works every time:

1. Get a shovel and start making a circle around the plant, the bigger the plant the bigger the circle.
2. Start to dig around the plant and go deep and try not to break to many roots.
3. When the plant has been dug around start to work the plant out of the ground, again not trying to break roots if possible.
4. Get a bag of any kind that will not break to easy (like a feed bag) if going a long distance.
5. When you get to the desired area take out of bag and plant like you normally would, make sure to give plenty of water.

That is that. For "Where to plant it": it really should not matter. We moved ours from one place to the next. Another thing to note, IT IS BEST TO DO THIS IN THE SPRING OR FALL. Doing it in the summer is not the best thing to do, not sure why but it is better to do it in cooler climates. Thus fall and spring. This works for a lot of plants that need to be transplanted, such as currents, gooseberries, strawberries, rhubarb and many others that I could think of.

Comment: Is there a desired angle, or anything?

Comment: what if i only have a root in soil from the lady selling the plant?

Comment: Light levels can be stronger in the summer, and the plants have leaves sensitive to it. So, that might be why the recommendation for spring/fall. As long as it gets enough water and isn't exposed to direct sunlight for a while after transplanting (and definitely not during or before transplanting after the roots disturbed), it should be fine. Misting the plant may help, too, as may extra potassium. Black currants are pretty indestructible around my house, although I haven't transplanted them in the middle of summer.

Comment: No, I have not found a desired angle or anything of the sort. When you say only a root I would imagine you mean there really isn't many of them? Because I would say that it could live, or it could die. The fewer roots the less the chance is how I would go with it. It would to hurt to try if you really wanted to if it is cheap enough.